# SQL Server limit SQL update using a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a contract table. When a change is made to a contract it will create a new record and set the active flag on the previous revision to false. This way, if someone views a contract signed in the past, they see the version they signed and not the revised version. In order to block any bugged code from making a change to any rows (and deleting rows). I want to use a trigger to block both of these actions. The issue is that if i use a trigger to block the update, how do i mark the active flag as false?

I have this much writte, but i do not know how to obtain the id. I am happy to make the assumption that the id will have been provided with the original update. id is the auto incremented PK so it needs to be provided. if it isnt i dont mind the server throwing an exception as no, code should be performing a query this way.

```
CREATE TRIGGER deactivate_contract
ON Contracts 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Contracts SET active = 0 WHERE id = ?    
END
```

Comment: If you dont want they update, just create a non edit user.

Comment: but i do want to edit. i want to be able to deactivate a row and nothing else

Comment: Check the inserted table.

Comment: then you have a different user with edit privelege for that? Not sure what is the problem